# Selenium - Trouble locating/interacting with login screen

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate a lot of my social media stuff, so I'm building an Instagram bot.  I CAN NOT seem to figure out the coding to locate and the input boxes and input my username/password.  I've tried finding elements by name, CSS selector, class name, etc.  I'm at a loss.  New to Selenium and kinda new to python.

Tried every method I've seen on forums, videos etc, and doesn't seem to work.

```py
class InstagramBot:

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions();
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", 
        ['enable-automation']);
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options);

    def login(self):

        self.driver.get 
        ('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')

        self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_2hvTZ pexuQ 
        zyHYP').send_keys(self.username)

        self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 
        'password')]")[0].send_keys(self.password)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    ig_bot = InstagramBot ('temp_username','temp_password')
    ig_bot.login()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the fields with the following css selectors:

```
"input[aria-label='Phone number, username, or email']"   // username
"input[name='password']"    // password
```

It is also a good idea to include waits for dynamically created elements

```
wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[aria-label='Phone number, username, or email']"))).send_keys(self.username)
wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']"))).send_keys(self.password)
```

Comment: Thank you!  Had to tweak this slightly and do one command to click, and a second line for the send keys.  Much appreciated!!